# Find matching string in one column and copy data from adjacent column to its own column

Tags: microsoft-excel

So I'm completely new to Excel but I need to put a lot of data into a readable document and I'm sick of entering it manually.

[image: Example of Data]

Here's a very small snippet of the data that I'm working with. As a quick example, I have been trying to find all instances of Type1 in Column1 and then take the string in Column2 that is in the same row and copy it over to Column3. I thought the Vlookup function would help me here but I never could get it to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Search for and watch a couple of videos of vlookup, and try their examples. Come back here if you still have specific questions.

Comment: Don't even need vlookup for this. Can just use a nested if if you are only doing the types. put this in column C and drag it down `=IF(A2="Type1", B2, IF(A2="Type2", B2, IF(A2="Type3", B2, "")))`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Filter function？

Such as `=FILTER(B1:B4,A1:A4="Type1")`.

[image]